# What is "as" doing in "given as"?

Tags: grammaticality, as

I heard in the movie *10 Cloverfield Lane*:

> I looked through your wallet. **Given as** how I saved your life, I think that's acceptable.

I find the interjection of "as" odd. When "given" is used as a preposition meaning "in view of" or "considering", shouldn't it be followed immediately by a noun phrase or a clause? Is the use of "as" here idiomatic or grammatical? "Given as how" returns zero hits on Google.

Comment: Ngram has hits for 'given as how' though more for 'given as I'. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=given+as+i&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgiven%20as%20i%3B%2Cc0

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22given+as+how+you%22&oq=%22given+as+how+you%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.651j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?num=20&newwindow=1&ei=tPd_W-eZBI2E5wKm_aDgCw&q=%22given+as+how+we%22&oq=%22given+as+how+we%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39.18043.18336..19474...0.0..0.61.118.2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.RVy_HZWU188

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22knowing%20as%20how%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never heard the expression **given as**: my impression is that it's an adaptation or corruption of **seeing as**, which the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/seeing-that?q=seeing%2Bas) says is an informal adaptation of **seeing that**, and defines it as "considering or accepting the fact that".

In formal conversation and writing, **[given that](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=given%20that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgiven%20that%3B%2Cc0)** is quite normal and has the same meaning, but in my opinion **given** rarely occurs in informal conversation, so it is very unusual- maybe just this one instance- to say **given as**.

One of the answers to this [EL&U question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37869/seen-as-or-seeing-as) gives more information about **seeing as**.

Comment: 'Given as ... ' doesn't sound odd to me at all; not common, perhaps, but certainly not unheard of. Given as I can't quote chapter & verse, you'll just have to take my word for it ;) [It does make me think it might be 'older' English; my native dialect is full of those, Northern Br E]

Comment: Imagine it said this way: *Given as 'ow I've paid for the first round, ...*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, put like that, it does sound quite northern... but I still think that "seeing as 'how" sounds more natural.

Comment: @JavaLatte: I bet you could find it in a Faulkner novel too.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo ah, American... I hadn't considered that.

Comment: There's a lot of northern England in the deep south.

Answer (score 1):

Compare:

Seeing as how

Knowing as how

Given as how

Thinking as how

Saying as how

Allowing as how

Telling as how

Letting on as how